# Question page seems to have incorrect time stamp on questions

Tags: bug, new-nav

I just went back to the question list page after viewing one, and I recognised a question I saw yesterday, yet the timestamp said it was a few minutes ago. Doing a refresh changed the list and the new page was all correct, but this was odd. Note this wasn't the same list I was looking at previously, I saw this a few days ago.

Is this just a weird Chrome caching issue, or is something else going on here?

[image]

EDIT: Just happened again. What I did was

1. Open New Tab
2. Go to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&pageSize=50"
3. View random question
4. Go back (this is where I see the old questions, and the "Strange Issue" one was asked "1 min ago"
5. Refresh the page and I get actual new questions.

Tried repeating straight after and step 4 was skipped, I just got new questions upon going back.

Comment: Yep, it a nutshell, the back button is broken.  It has been for a while.